# For Loop in object not functioning

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

I have leaflet object _test which looks like this
[image]
There are 4050 elements, and for all those elements I tried to run a loop and place label

```
    var a = Object.keys(_test);
    console.log(a.length);
    j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        var b = _test[a[i]];
        var vdc = L.polygon(b._latlngs);
        vdc_name = b.feature.properties.NAME_4;
        var labelLocation = new L.LatLng(vdc.getBounds().getCenter().lat, vdc.getBounds().getCenter().lng);
        var labelTitle = new L.LabelOverlays(labelLocation, vdc_name);
        VDC_labels.addLayer(labelTitle);
        console.log(vdc_name, j);
        j++}
```

The output in console for `console.log(a.length);` is 4050. But the last output of

```
console.log(vdc_name, j);
```

is **Sidin 1841**, which means the loop runs only 1841 times. Can anyone please help me find out what i am doing wrong?

I also tried with this but the result is the same

```
for (ath in _test) {
        var b = _test[ath];
        var vdc = L.polygon(b._latlngs);
        // console.log(i);
        // i++
        vdc_name = b.feature.properties.NAME_4; //label content
        var labelLocation = new L.LatLng(vdc.getBounds().getCenter().lat, vdc.getBounds().getCenter().lng);
        var labelTitle = new L.LabelOverlays(labelLocation, vdc_name);
        VDC_labels.addLayer(labelTitle);
    }
```

Comment: Need to know exactly what have you assigned to the variable a. Please make a jsfiddle and post it.

Comment: I have uploaded the code in https://gist.github.com/Poshan with descriptions 'label problems'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
Actually the problem is with the data i.e. in _test object the 1842nd element is a multipolygon unlike all other elements (polygon) so during the access of coordinate in

`var b = _test[a[i]];
var vdc = L.polygon(b._latlngs);`

b doesnot have the property _latlngs so the loop breaks..